# How to test iAd in iAd-unsupported country?

Tags: ios, iad

I'm in China which is not supported by iAd, but I want to embed iAd because my App is global. I'm aware that only US, UK, Japan.......can display iAd.

So how can I text iAd if I'm in China?

Or can I get revenue at all if I'm a iOS developer located in China?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Best idea is implement both iAd and GoogleAd(AdMob).

- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/supplementing-iad-placement-with-admob--mobile-9543